# Pivot table in CakePHP 3

Tags: mysql, associations, pivot-table, cakephp-3.0, crosstab

A product is available in many shops and each shop has a different price for that product.

```
+----------------------------------+
|         SHOP_PRODUCT             | 
+----------------------------------+
| product_id (PK + FK) e.g. 9      | 
| shop_id    (PK + FK) e.g. 5      |
| url                  e.g. ggl.com|
| price                e.g. 20.00  | 
+----------------------------------+
```

[image]

I want to be able to go in the product add template and add shops and price for the product.

How do I make these kind of associations in CakePHP 3?

Comment: Like that: **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-additional-data-to-the-join-table**. Also check out [**the `through` option**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to stablish a different entity as an intermediate table, in that case I would suggest product_prices or a more complete solution would be to make an product_stocks and that product_stock may have another table with the historic prices.

Another option is to add a surrogate key to the intermediate table that you were using initially, the reference information for that is here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option

Also by convention the name of the table should be `products_stores` as stated here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#database-conventions